# Best practice or behavior on duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, behavior, best-practices, duplicate-answers

If I ask a question, and somebody points out it's a duplicate, say I go and check the answers there and accept the fact that it is a duplicate (not necessarily an exact one, but it helps solve the problem). what should one do? Should you:

1. Leave it?
2. Request deletion?
3. Flag it?
4. other? what?

Same for exact duplicates, what should you do?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use an answer from the other question to solve the problem with very little or no changes to those answers then you should flag your question as an exact duplicate or vote to close (if you have enough reputation).

If you need to do a noticeable amount of work in addition to what was in the answer provided in the linked question (the solution needed significant adaptation to your situation, existing answers were incomplete or out of date, etc.), and you feel that the additional work that you've done would be useful to other people, then add an answer to your question that cites the answers that helped you and that explains how those answers needed to be adapted or updated to be appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I will **leave it** if the existing thread is not exact duplicate one, though it will help you to solve problem/issue. And yes will suggest to include more detail in the thread if possible so that it can be differentiated from the existing thread.

But as soon as I found it as exact duplicate one then i will **vote for close** (with duplicate) or **request for deletion**.

Answer (score 0):

> say I go and check the answers there and accept the fact that it is a duplicate (not necessarily an exact one, but it helps solve the problem)

If the question is (even slightly) different from the other one, because it's not exactly the same question, and there is a little difference in the context it's being asked, then I would leave it there. Often it happens to see a reply to a question that links another answer to a similar question, that (not fully) helps aswering to the asked question, with a further explanation.

If instead it's exactly the same question, with no context difference, then I would delete it.